# Dynamically Change Form Action Based on Selection Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you're well,

I try to figure what's wrong here. Action does not change. The URL does not work. I got this for each searches mydomain.com/?q=exemple. If anyone has an idea. I'll ne happy solve my issue.

```
<form id="myform" method="get" class="div-only-desk mr-2 my-auto w-100 order-1">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <select class="selectpicker bouton-catego dropdown-toggle" id="choicedb">
        <optgroup label="Nutriscore">
          <option>Autor</option>
          <option>Nutri</option>
        </optgroup>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <optgroup label="Cooker">
          <option>Find a cooker</option>
        </optgroup>
        {% else %}{% endif %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control border border-right-0h" name="q" type="text" placeholder="{{ q }}" aria-label="Search">
  </div>
</form>
```

js code

```
<script>
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Function to change form action.
    $("#choicedb").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        switch (selected) {
            case "Autor":
                $("#myform").attr('action', '/autor/');
                break;
            case "Nutri":
                $("#myform").attr('action', '/search/');
                break;
            case "Find a cooker":
                $("#myform").attr('action', '/earlycooker/cooktogether/');
                break;
            default:
                $("#myform").attr('/search/');
        }
    });
    // Function For Back Button
    $(".back").click(function() {
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});        
</script>
```

Comment: `var selected = $(this).children(":selected").text();` – the _children_ of your select field are the `optgroup` elements. None of those is ever `:selected`.

Comment: Why not just use `$(this).val()` and set the `value` attribute of the `option`s?

Comment: thanks a lot :) I'm a beginner with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var selected = $(this).children(":selected").text();
```

to:

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```